# PanGestureHandler immediately CANCELED after setState in React Native

Tags: react-native, pan, long-press, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

Guys im trying to mock up an Instagram profile with `react-native-reanimated` to preview a photo by long-pressing it and than by `PanGestureHandler` we can like the photo. 
But i have struggle here, when i want to long-pressing the photo, i want to change the current pressed image to state, so the pop up will render the current pressed photo, but the PanGesture's `State` immediately change to `CANCEL` and end the stream.
If i dont do the `setState`, all the gesture handler is running fine..

Please help, im new to react-native-reanimated, people doesnt share to much about this

Here is my code to render a single photo component ...

```js
import { TouchableOpacity, PanGestureHandler, LongPressGestureHandler } from 'react-native-reanimated';

class Instagram extend Component {

 ...........

  renderItem = (photo, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={index}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
        onPressIn={() => this.setState({currentImage: photo.image})} //when i try to set the state, onGestureEvent on PanGestureHandler immediately canceled
        onPress={this.onTapItem}
      >
        <LongPressGestureHandler
          ref={this.longPressRef}
          simultaneousHandlers={[this.panGestureRef, this.longPressRef]}
          onHandlerStateChange={this.onLongPressStateChange}
        >
          <Animated.View>
            <PanGestureHandler
              ref={this.panGestureRef}
              simultaneousHandlers={[this.longPressRef, this.scrollRef]}
              onGestureEvent={this.onPanGestureHandler}
              onHandlerStateChange={e => console.log(e.nativeEvent.state, 'PAN STATE <<<<<<')}
            >
              <Animated.Image
                style={styles.photoItem(index)}
                source={{ uri: photo.image }}
              />
            </PanGestureHandler>
          </Animated.View>
        </LongPressGestureHandler>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

   ..........
}
```